# What is the sample space of this data set?

Tags: probability, self-study, descriptive-statistics

I have a dataset containing stock market closing prices. My teacher told me to define the sample space for this data set. She asked whether the sample space was discrete or continuous.

Data:

```
Date        Close Price
3.02.2020   57599998
4.02.2020   57950001
5.02.2020   57150002
   .           .
   .           .
```

My answer:
I think it is not discrete since it is not like a dice or coin toss question. I also have trouble defining the sample space. I can't identify the sample space for this because we can't get a certain result like heads or tails.
Can you explain to me?

Comment: sample space is the possible range of output. For example, for coin flipping, the possible range of output is either head or tail, i.e. sample space is {head, tail}. For stock price, I think it the possible price is greater than zero, thus sample space is (0, +infinity). I don't think stock price can be exactly zero or negative values.

Comment: Thank you sir. What about the discrete or continuous subject? Is it discrete like i think?

Comment: Oh, continuous I think, because price can be decimal values, e.g. 12.21$

Comment: I disagree: Strictly speaking, it is discrete (think of the price in cents, instead of dollars, if it helps), but with a very large number of possible states. Therefore, for all practical purposes I can think of, you can approximate it by a continuous sample space. This is similar to approximating the binomial distribution by a normal distribution for large number of trials.